# Python: String Concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, string-concatenation

I'm starting out in Python and going through the book: Automate The Boring Stuff With Python.

I'm doing an exercise in chapter 4 called Comma Code. I'm supposed to be able to create a simple function that can take any list no matter what length e.g. ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats'] and output as: *apples, bananas, tofu, and cats*; the key being able to insert the word *and* between the last and second to last list value

I have written something which works (see below). But it outputs the values in new lines rather than on one line.

```
'''Practice Projects - Comma Code'''

def commacode(list_range):
    for i in range(len(list_range)):
        #print(i)
        position = len(list_range) - i
        #print(position)
        list_a = ''
        list_b = ''
        if position != 1:
            #list = ''
            list_a += str(list_range[i]) + ','
            print(list_a)
        else:
            list_b += list_a + ' and ' + str(list_range[i])
    print(list_a + list_b)

rangeoflist = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
commacode(rangeoflist)
#print(rangeoflist)
```

How can I get an output on one line?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `print(rangeoflist[:-1], f'and {rangeoflist [-1]}',sep = ", ")` ?

Comment: @Patrick Artner. Thanks. This was kinda alright but it returns a list value hence it still looks like a list. Output: ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu'], and cats. I could probably strip out the "]" and "["

Comment: `print(*rangeoflist[:-1], f'and {rangeoflist [-1]}',sep = ", ")` - missed an asterix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the sentence in one line, add `end=''` to first `print()`:

```
'''Practice Projects - Comma Code'''

def commacode(list_range):
    for i in range(len(list_range)):
        position = len(list_range) - i
        list_a = ''
        list_b = ''
        if position != 1:
            list_a += str(list_range[i]) + ','
            print(list_a, end='')                  # <-- add end='' here
        else:
            list_b += list_a + ' and ' + str(list_range[i],)
    print(list_a + list_b)

rangeoflist = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
commacode(rangeoflist)
```

Prints:

```
apples,bananas,tofu, and cats
```

---

Simpler code can be achieved by using `str.join`. For example:

```
rangeoflist = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
print(','.join(rangeoflist[:-1]) + ' and ' + rangeoflist[-1])
```

Prints:

```
apples,bananas,tofu and cats
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely. A little bit of progress in my Python journey. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/. I liked your simpler code. That may be the answer to this exercise actually.

Answer (score 2):

Python is quite elegant, when it comes to strings. I use `join` and array slicing.

```
rangeoflist = ['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
solution = " and ".join([", ".join(rangeoflist[:-1]), rangeoflist[-1]])
print(solution)
```

That's all code you need.